# Explicity show many-to-many tables in Entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I am attempting to learn Entity Framework to try to move on from Linq to SQL, and my attempt to convert some code over failed on a many-to-many recursive table (a tree structure).  I need to do a full table read and prepare the tree in memory because recursing through the database with a lot of queries is too slow.

I have a database with a Projects table, and another table called ProjectsTree.  With Linq to SQL, I can get access to the ProjectsTree table, but not with Entity Framework.  It puts it in an association in a way that I can't seem to query this table directly.

Here's the code before I attempted to convert Linq to SQL over to Entity Framework, and it worked.  Maybe I should stick with Linq to SQL and not learn something new, and if there is no way to do this, I may go backward, or let the two co-exist.

```
 Private Class cProjectTree2
      Public Project As PDMVault.Project
      Public ChildTree As List(Of cProjectTree2)

   End Class

   ''' <summary>
   ''' Gets the complete PDM project tree that can be added to a tree node.
   ''' Each node has the description in the node text field and the primary key in the tag.
   ''' </summary>
   ''' <returns></returns>
   Public Function GetPDMProjectTree() As TreeNode
      ' To generate the tree, first read the projects table with a complete table scan, then the ProjectTree with a complete table scan.
      ' Create a dictionary of objects of type cRecursiveProjectTree, but only the project is set on the first pass, with a reference to it based on its key.
      ' After the dictionary is built, then link up children to parent using the dictinary.
      ' Finally, use the created tree to create the node structure for the tree view.

      Dim Diag_Stopwatch As New Stopwatch

      Dim IDtoTree As New Generic.Dictionary(Of Long, cProjectTree2)

      Dim C = New PDMVault.DataContext1
      '  C.Log = Console.Out

      Dim Projects = C.Projects.ToList  ' Database list of trees.

''''''''''''''''''''''This is the line that fails.  ProjectTrees only shows up as an association, and I can't seem to get access to it for a full table scan 
          Dim Tree = C.ProjectTrees.ToList   ' Database hierarcy of the projects in the previous statement

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

      ' Create the dictionary with only the "Project" item set
      For Each P In Projects
         Dim ProjectTreeEntry As New cProjectTree2
         ProjectTreeEntry.ChildTree = New List(Of cProjectTree2)
         ProjectTreeEntry.Project = P
         IDtoTree.Add(P.ProjectID, ProjectTreeEntry)
      Next

      ' Now that the dictionary has been created, the children can be linked to the parent.
      For Each T In Tree
         Dim Parent As cProjectTree2 = Nothing
         Dim Child As cProjectTree2 = Nothing
         IDtoTree.TryGetValue(T.ProjectID, Parent)
         IDtoTree.TryGetValue(T.ChildProject, Child)
         Parent.ChildTree.Add(Child)
      Next

      ' The tree has been built, create the tree view from the tree (using a little recursion)


      Dim GetChildTrees As Func(Of cProjectTree2, TreeNode) =
         Function(P As cProjectTree2) As TreeNode
            Dim Result As New TreeNode
            For Each Child In P.ChildTree.OrderBy(Function(ProjectNode) ProjectNode.Project.Name)
               Dim N = GetChildTrees(Child)
               If N IsNot Nothing Then
                  Result.Nodes.Add(N)
               End If
            Next
            Result.Tag = P.Project.ProjectID
            Result.Text = P.Project.Name
            Return Result
         End Function

      Dim RootProject As cProjectTree2 = Nothing
      If IDtoTree.TryGetValue(1, RootProject) = True Then
         Dim N2 As TreeNode = GetChildTrees(RootProject)
         Return N2
      Else
         Return Nothing
      End If
   End Function
```

Comment: I think I can do it with a full table scan of Projects and select both the entry and its parent and I won't need access to the tree table.  I've noticed a few other quirks about Entities.  It doesn't like any external functions in your select statements, so sometimes you have to get as enumerable and then another select statement whereas Linq to SQL allowed external functions on select statements.

Answer (score 0):

I came very close to going backwards and sticking with LINQ to SQL, but this is a new project and I wanted to learn EF before I had significant code investment.  With a little experimenting with Entities Framework, the following handles the recursive tree nicely without me having to get access to the ProjectTrees table.

```
 Public Function GetPDMProjectTree() As TreeNode
      Dim Diag_Stopwatch As New Stopwatch
      Diag_Stopwatch.Start()

      Dim C = New PDMVault.DataContext1
      C.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = False ' Necessary for the materialization to work in the next line 
      Dim MaterializeDatabase = C.Projects.ToList

      C.Database.Log = Sub(Log) Debug.Print(Log) ' Verify that only two table scans occurs and that it's not hitting repeatedly

      Dim RootProject = (From P In C.Projects Where P.ProjectID = 1).SingleOrDefault

      If RootProject Is Nothing Then Return Nothing

      Dim GetTree As Func(Of PDMVault.Project, TreeNode) =
         Function(P As PDMVault.Project) As TreeNode
            Dim Result As New TreeNode
            For Each Child In P.Projects1.OrderBy(Function(ProjectNode) ProjectNode.Name)
               Result.Nodes.Add(GetTree(Child))
            Next
            Result.Tag = P.ProjectID
            Result.Text = P.Name
            Return Result
         End Function

      If RootProject Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
      Debug.Print($"Tree building time={Diag_Stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000:#0.00}")
      Return GetTree(RootProject)

   End Function
```

For the SO archives, here is a former method that did it with two trips to the database (one for the initial dictionary, and one for the root) and used an external dictionary before I learned about turning off lazy loading, probably not as optimal as my final solution.

```
 Public Function GetPDMProjectTree2() As TreeNode

      Dim Diag_Stopwatch As New Stopwatch

      Dim C = New PDMVault.DataContext1

      C.Database.Log = Sub(Log) Debug.Print(Log) ' Verify that only one table scan occurs and that it isn't an N+1 problem.

      ' Force a complete table scan before starting the recursion below, which will come from cached content

      Dim ProjectTreeFromDatabase = (From P In C.Projects
                                     Select Project = P,
                                            Children = P.Projects1).ToDictionary(Function(F) F.Project.ProjectID)


      Dim GetTree As Func(Of PDMVault.Project, TreeNode) =
         Function(P As PDMVault.Project) As TreeNode
            Dim Result As New TreeNode
            For Each Child In ProjectTreeFromDatabase(P.ProjectID).Children.OrderBy(Function(ProjectNode) ProjectNode.Name)
               Dim N = GetTree(Child)
               If N IsNot Nothing Then
                  Result.Nodes.Add(N)
               End If
            Next
            Result.Tag = P.ProjectID
            Result.Text = P.Name
            Return Result
         End Function

      Dim RootProject = (From P In C.Projects Where P.ProjectID = 1).SingleOrDefault
      If RootProject Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
      Return GetTree(RootProject)

   End Function
```

Both solutions prevent repeated trips to the database.

Comment: Oops :)  Maybe a try finally would have been better for testing tree building time.